# Matrix/Playa saving issue

Tags: matrix, playa, pixelandtonic

Have a problem with using Playa as a field within a Matrix field where the selected entry is not being saved.

Oldish version of EE (2.4) but should be supported. Entry appears to save okay but when revisit entry the field is empty.

Anybody got any thought?

Cole

Comment: What type of entry field is it? could it be a formatting thing. I had a field that did like this code i put in it so every time i saved it dumped the offending piece.

Comment: It's a Playa field/column within a Matrix field.

Comment: I'm not clear what your trying to do? are you making a playa selection and that is not being saved? Is the right play field selected in the Admin/Channel Fields? and finally can you update the P&P stuff at all? Just thought i'd try to trough out some ideas.

Comment: To clarify - I have a Matrix field and each row I want to relate to another entry so I am using Playa to choose an entry (single not multiple). In the control panel I can choose the entry just fine but when I save the entry and revisit the page or try to access the selected field via a template the response is empty.

Comment: Which version of Playa and Matrix are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - upgrading Matrix to the latest version (was 2.2 now 2.5) and tghis has fixed the issue.

Thanks for the feedback and suggestions folk!